# URL Query with ID not echoing student names

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table on one page where the user clicks on a college student and it takes them to their profile page. The profile is linked by

```
<a href="profilePage.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>" class="collection-item">
```

With the ID being the specific student. On the profilePage.php it shows the id on the URL but it is not printing out the name of the student. It is just blank with "Student name is  "

```
<?php
$idStudent = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']);
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE id = %s", $idStudent);
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$student = mysql_fetch_object($query);
?>

<p>Student name is <?php echo $student['student_Name'] ?></p>
```

I'm assuming it is how I'm calling the id and then query from the database. I'm using phpMyAdmin. This is how I connect to the database

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","server","password");
if (!$db) {
die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
}
$db_select = mysql_select_db("name",$db);
if (!$db_select) {
die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Again the problem is that the profilePage.php is not echoing the student name even though I have the ID in the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You URL is `id=<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>` and you are using `$_GET['ID']` to get that's wrong in your code `$_GET['id']!=$_GET['ID']`.You can get your id as

```
$idStudent = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);// use small id instead id ID
```

You are fetch your data in `object form`

```
$student = mysql_fetch_object($query);
```

SO instead of this

```
  <p>Student name is <?php echo $student['student_Name'] ?></p>
```

Use

```
<p>Student name is <?php echo $student->student_Name; ?></p>
```

> Note:- mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli OR PDO

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why they didn't work interchangeably

Answer (score 1):

In your query you searching `id` by `$_GET['ID']` there It can be error. 
if your DB table field ID then use below code

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE ID = %s", $idStudent);
```

Also place `;` when `echo` in PHP and you here resulting query as object so you have to echo object like brlow.

```
<p>Student name is <?php echo $student->firstName; ?></p>
```

and here

```
<a href="profilePage.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="collection-item">
```

Comment: Made the changes for syntax but still noting. It is coming from a table "student_info" where contains ID, firstName, year, classes.

Comment: change id to ID in <a href="profilePage.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="collection-item">

Comment: I updated my answer that will work now please check . echo firstName from database.

Comment: Got this to work! thanks! For some reason <p>Student name is <?php echo $student->firstName; ?></p> this syntax worked and not this <p>Student name is <?php echo $student['student_Name']; ?></p>